# What is my magento admin dashboard login url

Tags: magento2, admin, adminhtml, mamp

I recently installed magento on web and don't remember login

these links are not working and throw

> Whoops, our bad...
>
> The page you requested was not found, and we have a fine guess why.
>
> If you typed the URL directly, please make sure the spelling is
>   correct.
>
> If you clicked on a link to get here, the link is outdated.

http://localhost:8888/Magento/admin

http://localhost:8888/Magento/index.php/admin

http://localhost:8888/Magento/administrator

http://localhost:8888/Magento/index.php/administrator

i am using MAMP on mac yosemite and there is no local.xml in app/etc but yeah di.xml is there. thanks in advance

Comment: @ khan use command php bin/magento info:adminuri

Comment: @ krishna ijjada  Thanks you saved my day......

Answer (score 19):

To find out your admin URI you need to run the following command:

```
php bin/magento info:adminuri
```

It will give you an output like this:

> Admin Panel URI: /admin_1wgrah

Then you just need to append this result to your main URL

Answer (score 9):

You can also view the Admin URI in `<your Magento install dir>/app/etc/env.php`.

You can find something like below :

```
'backend' =>  
  array (
    'frontName' => 'admin_mdbdr2f',
  ),
```

Answer (score 2):

There are mainly two methods to check you M2 admin url

1. Via Command Line :  `php bin/magento info:adminuri` run this command.

   You will find output like : `Admin URI: /aurigait_admin`
2. Via Config File : Please open folder_name(adminlogger)/app/etc/env.php and search for backend frontname.

@magento2 @admin @adminlogger @aurigait